# Uniform consistency in discrete probability spaces

Tags: probability, self-study

I am trying to understand theorem 5.2.1 of Bickel and Doksum's Mathematical Statistics book. The theorem states that if $\mathcal{P} = \{(p_1, p_2, \ldots,p_k): 0 \leq p_j \leq 1, 1 \leq j \leq k,  \sum_{j = 1}^k p_j = 1\}$.
[image]

I understand the uniform continuity aspect of the problem, but I do not understand how we achieve the first inequality from there. I also do not understand how we can get the supremum to be $\leq k/4n\delta^2$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please tell us clearly what the "first inequality" is among the many inequalities that appear here (even among the highlighted ones).

Comment: Apologies. By first inequality I mean, $P(|\hat{q_n}-q|>=\epsilon|) <=P(|\hat{p_n}-p|>=\delta(\epsilon))$

Comment: But, allowing for some sloppiness in confounding $\gt$ with $\ge,$ that is an immediate consequence of the "implies" in the preceding sentence: it is an axiom of probability that the probability of a subset of any event cannot exceed the probability of that event.  For your second question about the supremum, this question refers you to Problem 5.2.1.  What hints does it give?  Chebyshev's Inequality, perhaps?

Comment: Thank you. So, the event $|\hat{q_n}-q| \geq \epsilon$ is a subset of the event $|\hat{p_n}-p| \geq \delta(\epsilon)$. For 5.2.1, I believe we have to use chebychev's inequality as we know that $P_p(|\hat{p_n}-p|\geq \delta) \leq var(\hat{p})/\delta^2$. Since $var(\hat{p})$ is maximized when $\hat{p}$=1/2, we get the upper bound to be $1/(4\delta^2 n)$. What I am having trouble with is how taking the sup across all p-s result in a factor k.

Comment: When each of $k$ probabilities is less than $1/(4n\delta^2),$ their sum is less than $k$ times that amount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(**Disclaimer**:  For less typing, the subscript $\mathbf{p}$ is suppressed in all the operators "$P, E, \operatorname{Cov}, \operatorname{Var}$" below, which should still be understood as "$P_\mathbf{p}, E_\mathbf{p}, \operatorname{Cov}_\mathbf{p}, \operatorname{Var}_\mathbf{p}$".)

The factor $k$ comes from the fact that $\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n$ is a $k$-dimensional random vector, so the Chebyshev's inequality goes as follows (more precisely, what we applied is [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality#Statement) with the one-dimensional random variable $X := |\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n - \mathbf{p}|^2$) :
\begin{align}
P[|\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n - \mathbf{p}| \geq \delta] 
\leq \frac{1}{\delta^2}E[|\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n - \mathbf{p}|^2]
= \frac{1}{\delta^2}E[(\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n - \mathbf{p})^T(\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n - \mathbf{p})] \tag{1}
\end{align}
There are many ways$^\dagger$ to evaluate $E[(\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n - \mathbf{p})^T(\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n - \mathbf{p})]$.  A convenient way is introducing the trace operator $\operatorname{tr}$ to link it with the covariance matrix of $\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n$:
\begin{align}
 & E[(\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n - \mathbf{p})^T(\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n - \mathbf{p})] \\
=& E[\operatorname{tr}((\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n - \mathbf{p})^T(\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n - \mathbf{p}))] \\
=& E[\operatorname{tr}((\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n - \mathbf{p})(\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n - \mathbf{p})^T)] \\
=& \operatorname{tr}[E((\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n - \mathbf{p})(\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n - \mathbf{p})^T)] \\
=& \operatorname{tr}[\operatorname{Cov}(\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n)]. \\
=& \sum_{j = 1}^k \operatorname{Var}(\hat{p}_j) \\
=& \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j = 1}^k\operatorname{Var}(N_j) \\
=& \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j = 1}^k np_j(1 - p_j) \\
\leq & \frac{k}{4n}, \tag{2}
\end{align}
where we used $\operatorname{Var}(N_j) = np_j(1 - p_j)$ if $(N_1, \ldots, N_k) \sim \text{Mult}(n; p_1, \ldots, p_k)$, and the inequality $p_j(1 - p_j) \leq \frac{1}{4}$.
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ then yields
\begin{align}
P[|\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n - \mathbf{p}| \geq \delta] \leq \frac{k}{4n\delta^2}. \tag{3}
\end{align}
Since the right-hand side of $(3)$ does not depend on the choice of $\mathbf{p}$, it is equivalent to the supremum-version inequality:
\begin{align}
\sup_{\mathbf{p} \in \mathcal{S}} P[|\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n - \mathbf{p}| \geq \delta] \leq \frac{k}{4n\delta^2}. 
\end{align}

---

$^\dagger$ A more straightforward way to evaluate $E[(\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n - \mathbf{p})^T(\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n - \mathbf{p})]$ is expanding the quadratic form then using the linearity of expectation:
\begin{align}
 & E[(\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n - \mathbf{p})^T(\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n - \mathbf{p})] \\
=& E\left[\sum_{j = 1}^k (\hat{p_j} - p_j)^2\right] \\
=& \sum_{j = 1}^k E[(\hat{p_j} - p_j)^2] \\
=& \sum_{j = 1}^k \operatorname{Var}(\hat{p}_j) \\
=& \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j = 1}^k\operatorname{Var}(N_j) \\
=& \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j = 1}^k np_j(1 - p_j).
\end{align}